# Search returns old records after indexing returns 200

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

The azure search returns old document after successfully indexing updated document. From the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents#response, it has been mentioned that indexing runs in background and may take few seconds before the document is updated.
Is there a rough estimated time or any API which can force update it or get the status.

Comment: Can you explain how you determine it is an "old" document. Describe what you do. I always add timestamp properties to every item I submit. That way I know the exact time when the item was submitted.

Comment: One of the field is lastupdatetime, which is the timestamp when the document was uploaded

Comment: Can you describe what you do? How do you test this specifically? There is a slight delay, but I would say it's a matter of seconds. Quicker than I'm able to test at least. I submit batches of 1000 documents at a time, and they are immediately available in the index. The API you ask for also exists since you can both submit and query using the SDK. In my implementation I have a boolean option in the method submitting content that controls if the method should wait until the item is confirmed index. You could also implement this a callback with events if you want.